# Dealing with 32-bit code on Snow Leopard 64-bit?

Tags: c++, osx-snow-leopard, 32bit-64bit

I would like to create an XPCOM plugin for a XULRunner application that I'm building. Since Mozilla only provides a 32-bit build of the XULRunner SDK I have to link with 32-bit libraries. This means that a lot of libraries need to be built by me.

Relating this I have a few questions:

Can I do a `sudo make install` for a 32-bit build? Or will it mess up my system?
If I can't do it, then what is the workaround?
My current solution is including the lib dir in the configure command:

```
CFLAGS=" -arch i386" CCFLAGS=" -arch i386" CXXFLAGS=" -arch i386" LDFLAGS=" -L`pwd`/../libs/gst-plugins-base -L`pwd`/../libs/liboil -arch i386" ./configure
```

Is this the way to go or are the better alternatives?

Comment: Do you need XPCOM? If not, using NPAPI would be easier and more portable.

Comment: I haven't created an NPAPI plugin yet, but I thought it was harder than XPCOM. I think I need XPCOM though for JS and DOM interaction (perhaps also possible with NPAPI).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sudo make install` will be fine, IF the installation location does not conflict with the system libraries.  In order to allow the built binaries to find your libraries, `otool` and `install_name_tool` are your friends.  For deployment, these will allow you to make everything bundle-relative even if it has been built for a different install location.

Comment: +1 for in-bundle deployment, probably always better for custom libraries.